# Search shows different numbers sometimes

Tags: bug, search

With the same environment and the same [filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios+or+iphone+or+objective-c+or+swift+or+xcode+or+uikit+or+swiftui+or+xcode15+or+cocoa-touch+or+uitableview+or+uitableview+or+xcodegen+or+swift-composable-architecture+or+visionos+or+swift-data?sort=Newest&uqlId=2923), sometimes the numbers are incorrect:

[image: First Image]

After a few refreshes:

[image: Second Image]

And after several more refreshes:

[image: Third Image]

The total number of questions rises and falls many times, while the bountied value changes less frequently.

I understand this might not be very critical, but I hope this platform continues to move toward perfection.

Here is a quick recording by hitting refresh (including the tags):

[image: demo]

Comment: Sure a bug, but most likely due to caching.

Comment: *" but I hope this platform continues to move toward perfection"*. Quite the opposite, unfortunately. The wrong people are fired, moderators have been demotivated, reviewing happens less and less, we're now not only trying to keep out bad questions and answers but also bad questions and answers which were lazily generated by software...

Comment: Sorry to hear that @Gimby, I personally always try my best to contribute, even if I get more downvotes for reporting a simple bug :)

Comment: It's not a bug if it's working as designed, within the expected parameters.

Comment: https://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Comment: Prove it. Count how many questions there actually are for that query at the exact moment you made the query and demonstrate that the count displayed differs from that count significantly.

Answer (score 4):

It would only be a bug if strong consistency was a desired attribute of the search results.

Probably not the case, since search is very likely performed across multiple replicas for a site as big as Stack Overflow; and eventual consistency would be a much more reasonable behavior for this scenario.

Notwithstanding that, with 1M results in the filter scope, one can expect some rather rapid variation as edits are performed on the targeted questions. Particularly with that many tags in the filter scope. The result is bound to vary frequently as tags and questions are added and removed.

Comment: Although this is theoretically true and expected, but you can see the changes in the `Active` tab (is there is any) and since it shows nothing, I think its not the case.

Comment: And also that happen sometimes for the `Bountied` value with just 13 results.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand how this "is not the case" when I say that it's likely expected that the results are "eventually consistent", and that the variation is the likely result of the search hitting different replicas. I'm afraid, I don't see how the "active" tab has any relevance.